# how to add star rating in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is the error that i got when i was trying to implement star ratings to my UITableView.
2012-09-28 18:41:33.698 PlanMyDay[4533:c07] adssadgadf(

(
    "4.5",
    "4.1",
    4,
    "3.9",
    "4.2",
    "4.1",
    "",
    "4.3",
    "3.9",
    "4.4",
    "",
    4,
    "3.9",
    "3.9",
    "",
    4,
    "3.2",
    "3.6",
    "3.3",
    "3.8"
)

> "2012-09-28 17:33:38.741 PlanMyDay[4211:c07] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0x1873022 0x13e5cd6 0x185fd88 0x4da43 0x5e2c54 0x5e33ce 0x5cecbd 0x5dd6f1 0x586d42 0x1874e42 0x1ba9679 0x1bb3579 0x1b384f7 0x1b3a3f6 0x1b39ad0 0x184799e 0x17de640 0x17aa4c6 0x17a9d84 0x17a9c9b 0x1a897d8 0x1a8988a 0x548626 0x2b82 0x2af5) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb) "

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        // if a cell can be reused, it returns a UITableViewCell with the associated identifier or nil if no such cell exists
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // if no cell to reuse, then create a new one
        if (cell == nil)
        {


    NSDictionary *testrate =[ratings1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",testrate];
    NSInteger n=[str intValue];
    NSLog(@"workrate:%@", str);

   if (n >=4)
        {


    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(65,60, 15, 15);
    //CGSize  starFrame = CGSizeMake(20,20);
    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    starImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

    CGRect starFrame1 = CGRectMake(80,60, 15, 15);
    UIImageView *starImage1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame1 ] autorelease];
    starImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    starImage1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage1];

    CGRect starFrame2 = CGRectMake(95,60, 15, 15);
    UIImageView *starImage2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame2 ] autorelease];
    starImage2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    starImage2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage2];

    CGRect starFrame3 = CGRectMake(110,60, 15, 15);
    UIImageView *starImage3 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame3 ] autorelease];
    starImage3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    starImage3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage3];

    CGRect starFrame4= CGRectMake(125,60, 15, 15);
    UIImageView *starImage4 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame4 ] autorelease];
    starImage4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
    starImage4.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage4];

    }
    else if(n >=3&&n<=4)
    {
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(65,60, 15, 15);
        //CGSize  starFrame = CGSizeMake(20,20);
        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        starImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];

        CGRect starFrame1 = CGRectMake(80,60, 15, 15);
        UIImageView *starImage1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame1 ] autorelease];
        starImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        starImage1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage1];

        CGRect starFrame2 = CGRectMake(95,60, 15, 15);
        UIImageView *starImage2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame2 ] autorelease];
        starImage2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        starImage2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage2];



    }


    return cell;
}
```

please help me to complete my project

Comment: You can put star frames to NSArray *starFrames and get the proper one by [starFrames objectAtIndex:i];

Comment: I cannot see any array in above code. The array makes the failure.

Comment: NSDictionary has been changed to NSArray

Comment: "NSArray *testrate =[ratings1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" this is the line which shows error exception

Comment: ratings1 is not initialised properly. Ain't it?

Comment: yes i did. actually i get the rating values from json and stored in a string by the code=[ratings1 addObject:rat]; i can print on console. but with the error

Comment: then give the rating1 print description right before exception arises

Comment: i didnt understand what u told at last..... could u specify me more with any code... it will more helpful...

Comment: Just debug to the line where the exception is, find the rating1 in the debugger window at the bottom. Left click will bring you context menu. Choose "print description of rating1" and paste result here. Edit your        question and add this paste to it.

Comment: i did but the same error was showing

Comment: You have no elements in rating1 array

Comment: sorry -pro i was also getting this in my console\log. Actually i am little freaked.Sorry

Comment: So the cause is elsewhere. Try to track down the place where you are adding elements to rating1 array

Answer (score 0):

Your array is out of index. Maybe your not instance it, or you try to access a null index of this array . . .

Answer (score 0):

Initialise ratigs1 correctly in method viewWillAppear

Comment: So... how many elements does it have after initialising? In my opinion elements count is 0, so this gives an exception when you try t read obect at index 1

Comment: 20. i got from json data that all are printing in console but it be set as star rating